# okhttp3 post request does not work when using requestbody on kotlin

Tags: html, kotlin, okhttp

Im using a node js server to recieve post requests from a kotlin script on android studio, but whenever i send a requestbody my server just recieves an empty {}.

node js side:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
  
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}));

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.json(null);
});
  
app.listen(65123, function(){
  console.log("running");
})
```

android studio side:

```
private fun sendFile(ip: String, file: File) {
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
        val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("file", file.name)
            .build()
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(ip)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build()
```

First i tried sending files and then only the name but neither worked

Comment: You're sending the file as a "multipart" request, but apparently `body-parser` doesn't support multipart request bodies (see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser))